# how to import Helper class in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a helper class in react. The image below shows my setup:

[image]

In my App.js, I have:

```
import  Helpers  from './Helpers.js'
```

I have also tried:

```
 import  Helpers  from './components/Helpers.js'
 import  Helpers  from 'src/components/Helpers.js'
 import  Helpers  from './components/Helpers.js'
 import  Helpers  from 'src/components/Helpers.js'
 import  {Helpers}  from './components/Helpers.js'
 import  {Helpers}  from 'src/components/Helpers.js'
```

and I have also tried, in my Helpers.js:

```
export default Helpers
export default Helpers();
```

However, I receive an error message:

```
'./Helpers.js' does not contain an export named 'Helpers'.
```

It seems as though App.js can not find and locate this class. How can I import it, so i can just call the functions, like:

```
Helpers.helperFunctionHere();
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** Export each function individually

In Helpers.js

```
export function helperFunctionHere() {
    console.log("hello there");
}
```

In App.js

```
import {helperFunctionHere} from "./Helpers";

render() {
    helperFunctionHere();
}
```

**Option 2:** Static properties on the class

In Helpers.js

```
class Helpers {
    static helperFunctionHere() {
        console.log("hi");
    } 
}
export default Helpers
```

In App.js

```
import Helpers from "./Helpers";

render() {
    Helpers.helperFunctionHere();
}
```

Comment: Hi @harshpatel991, I use the exactly same code as you mention. But get error "Attempted import error: 'Helpers' is not exported from '../Helpers'." Can you help me plz

Answer (score 0):

Should be `export default Helpers`. Am also assuming that your bundler is setup correctly.

Comment: still receiving an error:   
  ./src/components/App.js 

Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Helper.js' in '/Users/joey/testing/src/components'